# Rewriting URL's with and without trailing slash

Tags: apache

I'm at my wits end on this and don't understand Apache (like, at all) or care to.

I'm attempting to be able to visit my site by going to a url in two ways:

example.com/page

example.com/page/

both using page.html as the data source. I've been told to use multiviews (which enabling did nothing). I've always seen this done with mod_rewrite.

Current .htaccess that does not work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## Hide .php extension by external redirection:
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R,NC,L]

## Internally redirect to .php extension:
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

Comment: Does the directory `page/` exist? If so, `MultiViews` would fail.

Comment: It might help if you tell us what the current state is, so what actually happens, any error messages you get in the log files and what the output of rewrite logging is.